# how to get param in permission.py django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to work with 'start' param in permissions.py
How I can take it ?
My model

```
class Quiz(models.Model) :
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    start = models.DateTimeField(default="2021-10-10")
    end = models.DateTimeField(default="2021-10-11")

    description = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

permissions.py

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsTimeNotDefined(permissions.BasePermission) :
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return False
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `has_object_permission` instead of `has_permission`.
Not that it only works for object-level actions like `retrieve`, `update` and `destroy`. Not `list` and `create`.

```py
def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
    obj.start
```